How do I remove a 3 way switch from this system?
I've got a light that's on two three-way switches. The setup is like the image below, where power comes into a junction box, and there are two sets of wires coming out, one set that goes to the light fixture, and one that goes to the second switch.  I know that I need to tie some of the wires together, but I'm not sure which.

Can anyone guide me through removing the line (switch on the left) and make the switch on the right (the load side switch, if I understand the term correctly, which I probably don't) a single pole switch?  I'm kind of at a loss!

It should be pretty simple. HOWEVER, while you might think the switches match the diagram, they might not. The color coding may be different (always black/red/white but used in different ways), line vs. load may be different (in fact, in the diagram the left switch is load and the right switch is line!), the position of traveler vs. common screws on the switches may be different, etc. WE NEED PICTURES OF THE EXISTING WIRING/SWITCHES. That is the only practical way to figure this out. Even then, some testing with a multimeter may be needed. Turn off power, pull out the switches (but

don't disconnect any wires) and upload pictures that clearly show wire colors and positions for each cable and each switch.

Three way switches are sometimes needed to meet code. If the switches are at 2 different entrances to a room or at top and bottom of a staircase, removing one switch may put the wiring in non-compliance of  building code.

the line goes to the right switch

I agree with @RMDman.  Unless they are used for a reading lamp on each side of a bed/sofa or accent lamps, the two switches are required by code at each entrance to a room.  Add information about their use/location to the question.

There will be two switches, but I upgraded to a smart switch, and the second switch doesn't require wiring.  They're in a bedroom, but the second switch is just in a point that's closer to the bed.  To be honest, I don't even need it to be a three way, but since the box is already there, it makes more sense to have a switch than a blank plate.
